# How to call another restapi from rest api in same process using restEasy

Tags: rest, jax-rs, resteasy

I have rest api '/users/{id}/checkin' in which i want to do some processing and call another rest api on different resource but in same service. For example.

```
ServiceResource.java
@GET
@path(/services/checkin/)
public Response checkinUser(User user)
{

      // --- processing.
    }


    UserResource.Java
@POST
@path(/users/{id}/checkin/)
public Response verifyUser(@PathParam("id) String id)
{

       // --- Get the users from the iD.
       User user = getUsers(id);

      // --- need to call service from the serviceResource.

}
```

Any idea how to do it? as i want to avoid the HTTPclient call.

Comment: It is a public method, just call it like a normal function. Make a object and call it.

Comment: Hello Rjiuk, Thanks for reply however i dont want to do the same as i want it  loosely coupled it. Calling method will add direct dependency.

Answer (score 2):

Put all method definitions and the resteasy annotations in an interface and use this interface as input to the resteasy proxy framework.

See [documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/docs/3.1.0.Final/userguide/html/RESTEasy_Client_Framework.html#d4e2297) for details.

ServiceResourceIF.java:

```
public interface ServiceResourceIF {

    @GET
    @path(/services/checkin/)
    public Response checkinUser(User user);

}
```

The calling code could look like this (stolen from the original documentation of resteasy, see link above):

```
User = new User(...);

Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient();
WebTarget target = client.target("http://your.service.url/base/uri");
ResteasyWebTarget rtarget = (ResteasyWebTarget)target;

ServiceClient service = rtarget.proxy(ServiceResourceIF.class);
service.checkinUser(user);
```

Note: You can use the same interface to configure the client and server.

Comment: Hello martinw, Thanks for the reply,

Comment: Can you please upvote or accept the answer if it helped you? Thanks!

Comment: However, is there any way where i can directly get the method from the URL or direclty invoking the method from the resteasy for provided URL.

Comment: I am afraid that I outlined the simplest way in my answer already. RESTeasy needs some minimal information about the service (like the method and parameters) and this is given in the interface. If you use the interface to define the server side as well this will not give you any additional overhead. Of course you could encapsulate all the above code in a method of your class but you have to do it on your own.